# Set unit for X and Y coordinate in TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

I want to put image 1 cm after the page top,

```
            $this->Image($image_link, 25, 10, 20, '', 'png', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
```

25 is the x coordinate and 10 is the Y coordinate, the think is i don't know what unit used in this code or default unit used by tcpdf for x and y coordinate.

I have read the documentation, and only found setting unit measurement for margin.